# A convex version of the small uncountable cardinal $\mathfrak b$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, convexity, infinite-combinatorics, cardinal-characteristics

Let us recall that $\mathfrak b$ is the smallest cardinality of a subset of $\omega^\omega$, which cannot be covered by countably many compact subsets of $\omega^\omega$.

The definition of $\mathfrak b$ implies that for any set $B\subseteq X$ of cardinality $|B|<\mathfrak b$ in a Polish space $X$ and any countable subset $C\subseteq B$ the complement $B\setminus C$ is contained in a countable union of compact subsets of the space $X\setminus C$.

I am interested in a convex version of this property.

> **Problem 1.** Let $B$ be a linearly independent subset of cardinality $|B|<\mathfrak b$ in a separable Banach space $X$, and $C$ be a countable subset of $B$. Can $B\setminus C$ be covered by countably many compact convex subsets of $X\setminus C$?

Problem 1 can be reformulated using the cardinal $\mathfrak b'$ defined as the smallest cardinality of a linearly independent subset $B$ of a separable Banach space $X$ such that for some countable set $C\subseteq B$ the complement $B\setminus C$ is not contained in the union of a countable family of compact convex subsets of $X\setminus C$. It is clear that $\omega_1\le \mathfrak b'\le\mathfrak b$. Problem 1 asks whether $\mathfrak b'=\mathfrak b$?

> **Problem 2.** Is it consistent that $\omega_1<\mathfrak b'$? In particular, is $\mathfrak b'=\mathfrak c$ under Martin's Axiom?